# Select DISTINCT multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am having trouble in retrieving DISTINCT records. Scenario is as follow:
Right now my query is

```
Select a,b,c from TABLE_NAME
(COMPLEX_INNER JOIN LOGIC)
```

I want records where first two column values should be unique. I know this can be done by

```
GROUP BY
```

Clause. So the query will become

```
Select a,b,c from TABLE_NAME
(COMPLEX_INNER JOIN LOGIC)
GROUP BY a,b
```

But as c is not appearing in aggregate function or group by SQL server is giving following error:

**Column 'c' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.**

Comment: how can you select 2 column distinct when you're selecting 3 columns.... isn't it against logical use of distinct/group by ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your query in a CTE and use the [row_number()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function to figure out what rows to fetch.
Something like this:

```
with C as
(
  Select a,b,c,
         row_number() over(partition by a, b order by SomeColumn) as rn
  from TABLE_NAME
  --(COMPLEX_INNER JOIN LOGIC)
)
select a, b, c
from C
where rn = 1
```

Working sample:

```
declare @T table
(
  a int,
  b int,
  c int
)

insert into @T values
(1, 1, 1),
(1, 1, 2),
(2, 2, 1),
(2, 2, 2)

;with C as
(
  select a, b, c,
         row_number() over(partition by a, b order by c) as rn
  from @T         
)
select a, b, c
from C
where rn = 1
```

Result:

```
a           b           c
----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           1
2           2           1
```

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
select c,q.a,q.b from TABLE_NAME inner join 
(
Select a,b from TABLE_NAME
(COMPLEX_INNER JOIN LOGIC)
GROUP BY a,b) q 
on q.a=TABLE_NAME.a
```